# Open special file types/extensions in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, jetpack

I want to open special file types with extension like ".d83" (plain text), ".x83" (special XML) in Jetpack Compose. I don't see how to do that in androidx.activity.compose.rememberLauncherForActivityResult.

Comment: Unclear who should open those files. Your app? Or an external app?

Comment: rememberLauncherForActivityResult does not open files. So what is it that you are after?

Answer (score 0):

That is not directly supported in Android. Jetpack Compose does not improve the situation.

If you wish to use platform-supplied things like `ActivityResultContracts.OpenDocument`, you will need to let users open files of any MIME type (`*/*`), then inspect the contents to see if they are formatted as you expect.